# How to integrate WCF and SOAP to existing server-client application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf-client, soapserver

I am new to server-client applications.

I am trying to build a prototype where a Java server communicates with a .net WPF client over http. The server and client currently communicate over a third-party messaging system(Tibco). I have done a bit of research and have decided on using SOAP and WCF. I have been trying to find tutorials on how to implement this but cant seem to find anything that fits my need. If anyone could point me to some resource that a newbie like me could use to come up to speed with implementing SOAP and WCF to existing system I'd really appreciate it. Also if anyone has any suggestion on any other protocol that could be used, feel free to recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did this at work to support some 3rd party interop scenarios and our process looked like:

1. Generate a WSDL for our WCF service via the wsdl.exe tool (we defined a basic HTTP version of our services because of the lack of eventing in Java),
2. Used an apache CXF tool, wsdl2java, to generate Java classes for the WSDL,
3. Used the autogen'd client definition as a wrapper to perform calls on the server.

I'd imagine in your case you'd do the exact opposite, using java2ws.exe in the Apache CXF framework to create your WSDL, then using wsdl.exe in the .Net framework to generate your c# classes (or other CLI classes...), then consuming those classes to accomplish whatever it is you have a client do.

Here's the API page for the CXF Java->WSDL tool - http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-ws.html
And for the WSDL.exe .Net tool - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.71).aspx